# Pegar apenas primeira palavra dentro de uma consulta sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Boa tarde srs,
Tenho a seguinte query

```
SELECT COUNT (SolID) as quant, UsuNome as gerador 
FROM Solicitacao 
INNER JOIN Usuario ON Solicitacao.UsuIDAtendenteViaFone = Usuario.UsuID
WHERE UsuIDGrupo = 2655
AND DATEPART(m, SolData) = DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, 0, getdate()))
AND DATEPART(yyyy, SolData) = DATEPART(yyyy, DATEADD(m, 0, getdate()))
GROUP BY UsuNome order by quant desc
```

Essa query me retorna isso:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso que a coluna gerador retorne apenas o primeiro nome.

Answer (score 7):

Não tem muito segredo:

```
SELECT COUNT (SolID) as quant, 
    SUBSTRING(UsuNome, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', UsuNome, 1) - 1) as gerador 
FROM Solicitacao 
    INNER JOIN Usuario ON Solicitacao.UsuIDAtendenteViaFone = Usuario.UsuID 
WHERE UsuIDGrupo = 2655 
  AND DATEPART(m, SolData) = DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, 0, getdate())) 
  AND DATEPART(yyyy, SolData) = DATEPART(yyyy, DATEADD(m, 0, getdate())) 
GROUP BY UsuNome 
order by quant desc
```

Explicando:

```
SUBSTRING(UsuNome, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', UsuNome, 1) - 1)
```

O primeiro argumento é a coluna propriamente dita. O segundo é o início da *substring*, e o terceiro é o final da *string*, o qual uso a função `CHARINDEX` para achar a primeira ocorrência de um espaço.

Comment: Valeu cara, é inexperiência mesmo, hehehe